# Google Search Console keeps telling me my content is wider than screen when it isn't

Tags: google-search-console

It's happening multiple times per month at this point, basically randomly, to different pages on my wiki. Every... single... time... I go to the page in question, view it with a simple inspect, check the narrowest mobile setting (typically iphone 6), and it's fine.

Then I just go back to the search console, and click validate fix. In the next day or two, it comes back and congratulates me for fixing the issue.

This is the url of the last iteration of this happening: https://golfcourse.wiki/course/presidio_golf_course-san_francisco/holes/1

This has been happening for months. Am I missing something here? Is this normal?